# Remove section numbering but retain the short-title optional argument

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I have a section like that:

```
\section[ABC]{ABC\footnote{FN1}\footnote{FN2}}
```

I want to remove section numbering, but I must use `\section[]{}`.

So when I try

```
\section*[A]{B}
```

I get only

```
 [
```

Here is my example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}


\title{}
\date{}
\begin{document}


\section[TST 2012]{TST 2012\footnote{30 March-31 March-1 April 2013}}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 

\end{enumerate}


\section[TST 2013]{TST 2013\footnote{30 March-31 March-1 April 2013}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\section*` doesn't add a TOC entry an thus the second argument is pointless (and unsupported). If you want all sections to be unnumbered, set `secnumdepth` instead.

Comment: This is what I search for.

Comment: @You: Why don’t you extend your comment to an answer that the OP can accept …?

Comment: @You -- in some document classes, the section title is also used for running heads, and for that purpose, the optional argument is *not* pointless when a title is very long.  yes, there are workarounds, but in my estimation, this was a bad design oversight.

Answer (score 2):

with koma script, you can use `\addsec`. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addsec{test}
\end{docum‌​ent}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the aim is to hide the numbering of all sectioning commands (except parts and chapters), while still keeping them in the TOC, you can instead set the `secnumdepth` counter and continue using `\section` un-starred:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\title{}
\date{}
\begin{document}


\section[TST 2012]{TST 2012\footnote{30 March-31 March-1 April 2013}}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 

\end{enumerate}


\section[TST 2013]{TST 2013\footnote{30 March-31 March-1 April 2013}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Whether the OP wants to remove section numbering of only one or of every section while still retaining the short title is unclear.